# Возвратить частичное представление в ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Не могу получить частичное представление из метода контроллера, в чем может причина

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelPage => modelPage.MenuNews.NamePeriod, new SelectList(new[] { "Все", "Год", "Месяц" }), "День", new { @class = "period_date", @id = "period_date", @onchange = "FillCity()" })
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FillCity()
    {
        var stateId = $('#period_date').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMenuNews", "News")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { periodUpdate: stateId },
            success: function (periodUpdate) { $('#target_popular_menus').html(result)}
         });
    }
</script>
```

метод контроллера

```
    public ActionResult UpdateMenuNews(string periodUpdate)
    {
        Models.PageNews _filterPanelNews = new Models.PageNews();
        asamtech.Models.Db_Initializer _InitializerPageNews = new Models.Db_Initializer();
        _filterPanelNews.MenuNews.NamePeriod = periodUpdate;
        _filterPanelNews.MenuNews = _InitializerPageNews.GetMenuPanelNews(_filterPanelNews.MenuNews);
        _filterPanelNews.MenuNews.PopularName[0] = "1111111111111111111111";
        return PartialView("_PopularNewsMenu", _filterPanelNews);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр periodUpdate должен отправляться и приниматься

```
function FillCity()
    {
        var stateId = $('#period_date').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMenuNews", "News")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            async: true, 
            contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { periodUpdate: stateId },
            success: function (periodUpdate) { $('#target_popular_menus').html(periodUpdate);},
            failure: function (response) {alert(response.responseText);},
            error: function (response) {alert(response.responseText);}
            });
    }
```

Comment: спасибо помогло